# Android - DataBinding - How and when the Binding classes will be generated?

Tags: android, data-binding

[DataBinding Guide](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html) States

```
  By default, a Binding class will be generated based on the name of the layout 
file, converting it to Pascal case and suffixing “Binding” to it. 
The above layout file was activity_main.xml so the generate class was ActivityMainBinding.
```

When will the Binding class , here say ActivityMainBinding, will be generated. I have compile time error. "cannot resolve ActivityMainBinding".

```
ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.main_activity);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @DerGol...lum, Ya i know, it is beta release. I just want to try it out.

Comment: According to this Paragraph it is ok from Google's perspective to publish apps using this library. You just have to keep aware of the beta status and the implications:          *** Developers should feel free to publish apps built with the Data Binding library beta release, with the caveats that the standard Android SDK and Google Play terms of service apply, and it’s always a great idea to test your app thoroughly when adopting new libraries or tools.

Comment: Can anyone point to where the generated classes/files are located in the project?

Comment: Just for the completeness :
all generated code is inside "module_dir"/build/generated. Further below
 as per resources there is res directory as per java classes there is src with affinities (e.g. dataBinding). This structure is generated by gradle 2.2+

Comment: In my case, the databingclass is updated timely if there is element <data></data> in the xml file, or it is only updated after reopening the studio IDE.

Comment: 3 years later and Android Studio *still* doesn't generate the binding files reliable. PRO TIP: avoid MVVM in Android.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

What is your layout name?

> The above layout file was activity_main.xml so the generate class was ActivityMainBinding.

What this means is that the generated class name will depend on your layout's name 
activity_main.xml -> ActivityMainBinding.java

I think your activity name is "main_activity", so the generated binding class name should be MainActivityBinding not ActivityMainBinding

Comment: It's definitely confusing in this case that classes are postfixed with "Activity" while xmls are prefixed!

Comment: This doesnt answer the question of "how and when". I'm having the same issue as the OP, the binding file is NOT GENERATED for me. This answer just tells you about the naming convention, and doesnt give any clue as to how to resolve the issue of the missing file.

Comment: @Siavash I don't know 'How & When', but I had a similar problem, and what fixed it for me was putting all of the xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" stuff in the layout tag instead of the top view tag. It was just an oversight on my part, but it was driving me crazy, so I figured I'd pass it on in case it helped someone else.

Comment: Kindly help me i have a package name like com.asadmukhtar.show and xml file name is activity_splash, after data binding enable my binding file always generate in package like com.example why this happen i am following MVVM model. kindly help me

Answer (score 35):

When it's not generating the binding class, I restart Android studio. Then the binding class will be generated. Isn't it caused by cache of android studio?

BTW, if you are using `android-apt`, please check it. Because it will cause binding class not to be generate.

Comment: yes restart worked and issue is still there in Android Studio 2.1

Comment: True and better to Invalidate cache And restart ... that happens if you activate Databinding after creating layout..

Comment: As 08/16 I have this issue if more than one instance of AndroidStudio is open. I had to restart to see the binding suffix class.

Comment: with me, the binding file exists in `\Project\app\build\generated\source\apt\development\debug\project\android\app\databinding` HOWEVER Android Studio 3.1.3 is reporting the class as Unknown. Invalidate Caches and Restart is not fixing it.

Comment: also, Android Studio keeps generating an error `com.intellij.psi.PsiInvalidElementAccessException: Element: class com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlFileImpl because: different providers`. What a waste of time !

Answer (score 32):

Did you update your layout file for data binding? They are generated only for layouts which have data binding.

It has to start with a `layout` tag which has 2 child tags (data & your root view).

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <data>
       <variable name="user" type="com.example.User"/>
   </data>
   <LinearLayout ...
   </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

When your layout has this form, AndroidStudio should auto complete the class. Also, by default, it is generated in `<your.app.package>.databinding` package.

Comment: Even if you're not using Android Studio, the gradle plugin will generate the code during the annotation processing stage. Without Android Studio, you'll have to have faith that the class will be generated and import the Binding class yourself. Something like "import com.my.package.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;" for activity_main.xml

Comment: Class wasn't generated when I had only <layout> and no <data>. When I added <data> with some <variable>, class got generated.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, no <data> tag was my problem. Even works without adding a variable, by the way.

Comment: This solved it for me. That layout section is needed for the binding to be generated

Answer (score 16):

#### Rule

Layout name is in **`snake_case`**, and generated binding class name will be **`PascalCase`**.

> If you layout name is `activity_home.xml` then binding class name will
>   be `ActivityHomeBinding.class`.

#### Problem

1. Many times you don't get import suggestion of DataBinding class.
2. Binding class is not generated when there is some issue in layout.
3. Binding class are not available when build is failed

#### Here is hack

#### When you Don't get Import Suggestion

- When you don't get import suggestion. Import manually your binding class like this. (IDE often does not show suggestions for binding classes)

  ```
  import <yourpackage>databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
  ```

#### Import line still shows error?

- If your import line shows error, then try **make project** (ctrl + F9) / **Build> Make Project**. .

  1. If Build is failed due to some error, then solve it.
  2. If build is successful then binding class will be generated.

#### Quick hack for generating binding class-

- If your binding class not generated then **close project** (File > Close Project) and **open from recent**.

**Note that** I recommend **close and open** from recent because it takes **less time** than **Rebuild** / **Restart IDE**.

#### Quick hack for generating layout variables in binding class-

- If your layout data variable are not generated then **close project** (File > Close Project) and **open from recent**.

If you still have issues. Let me know in comments, or see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579759/6891563) for better understanding.

Answer (score 15):

**Try to rename layout to `main_activity.xml`.**

In my case, it didn't work to generate binding class for "activity_main.xml".
But renaming the layout file to `main_activity.xml` worked just fine.

Comment: It worked for me too. From now on, I will use ´xxxxxx_activity.xml´ for all of my activities/fragments as a new naming convention. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the layout of the:

```
 <data>
   <variable name="user" type="com.example.User"/>
 </data>
```

Is in the **activity_main.xml** if you are looking for ActivityMainBinding. In most boilerplate projects you set your content view to activity_main.xml, but then inflate you fragment_main.xml.

If you put your `<data>` in **fragment_main.xml** layout then the class that is generated will be **FragmentMainBinding**.

Note: This may seem obvious after reading, but it is something that can be easily overlooked when following the android documentation.

Answer (score 4):

If you ever wanted to give your own Binding class name just add `class` attribute to the `data` element with class name

> Binding classes may be renamed or placed in different packages by adjusting the class attribute of the data element.

```
<data class="ContactItem">
    ...
</data>

<data class="com.example.ContactItem">
...
</data>
```

Comment: Restarting Android Studio as posted by @Frank Cheng does work, However it makes it tedious to restart it every time a new layout is created. I opted for this option of naming the binding classes my self as it seems to work without problems.

Answer (score 4):

In my case Restarting Android Studio does work. It is bug in android-apt

Answer (score 2):

Just a simple restart didn't work for me. I had to `Invalidate Caches and Restart` then I could see the binding classes. It's under the `File` menu for those who don't know.

Answer (score 1):

For android databinding to work properly you have to use android tools for gradle (com.android.tools.build:gradle) >=1.3.0.

So your project build.gradle must look like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc1"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

And module build.gradle must have that plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'
```

After all, check in your module you're using latest buildToolsVersion (right now it is 22.0.1). I am not sure that's required but it possibly will make you feel good about you're on the "bleeding edge of technology" ^_^ :

```
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
```

Resync gradle and **rebuild your project**. It is likely possible that without rebuild of project you might not get `SomeLayoutBinding` classes generated.

In Android Studio that could be done from application menu: `Build -> Rebuild project`

Comment: this will cause error posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35250956/error3-0-cause-org-apache-commons-lang3-stringutils  (Error:(3, 0) Cause: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils)

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue.

Reason for "cannot resolve ActivityMainBinding" is that your Binding file isn't generated. Try to clean and rebuild project.
Also make sure you have followed the steps :

1. **classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc4"** --> include this in **main module** build file
2. **apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'** to your **app module** you are building
3. Clean
4. Rebuild. Check under ,if build->indermediates->your package name->databinding folder is generated containing ActivityMainBinding class.

Alternatively if you want to see the generated source.

1. **classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.7'**   -->apply to your main module.
2. **apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'** --> to you app module
3. **apt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:1.0-rc0'** --> include in your dependencies.

These classes will be generated on first build.
Also make sure the **applicationId** in your application module is same as the **package name** in AndroidManifest.xml of your app module.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that Android Studio 3.1.3 generated the databinding class after I clicked "Build > Rebuild Project". The file was stored in:

\Project\app\build\generated\source\apt\development\debug\project\android\app\databinding

However, Android Studio *still* reported the binding class as "Unknown" in source code.

To finally fix it, I **manually** added the **import** statement:

> import project.android.app.databinding.*;

Answer (score 0):

A weird "bug" in android-studio causes the generated BR.java file not to use the `@Bindable` fields and still only have the `_all` property if a res/layout directory doesn't exist.

It happened to me when I wanted to create a "No Activity" App to have a library that contained my different bindable data.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i just enclosed my layout xml in `<layout></layout>` tags and that's it, without adding the data tag, i was successful to generate Data Bindings. Hope this helps.

```
<data>
       <variable name="user" type="com.example.User"/>
</data>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<data class="MainActivityBinding">
    <variable
        name="user"
        type="com.example.administrator.my_mvvm.User" />
</data>
```

//Remember need 
Build-> Rebuild Project

Answer (score 0):

check the fields access level of your object, when i turned public it worked here

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to restart android studio, one way is to rename activity_main.xml to something else e.g activity_m.xml and then rename it back to activity_main.xml. It is much faster than restarting android studio.

To rename, right click on activity_main.xml and choose **Refactor** => **Rename**

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue that hasn't been mentioned here yet.  In my case, I incorrectly added `<Layout>` as the tag versus `<layout>`.  `<Layout>` is apparently a valid tag because Android Studio didn't complain (other than requiring layout_width and layout_height which aren't required for `<layout>`).  The capitalization difference will manifest in similar behavior where you cannot import the databinding class (import com.example.android.aboutme.databinding.ActivityMainBinding in my case) in the MainActivity class even though `<Layout>` is a valid tag and the build.gradle file is defined properly to support data binding.

In my case, I did not need the `<data>` tags defined yet in order for ActivityMainBinding to validly import and be referenced in:

`private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding`

I was working through the this codelab when I ran into this behavior: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-data-binding-basics/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi maybe you can try this as well include this in build.gradle(:app)

inside the android block

buildFeatures {
viewBinding true
}

worked for me, maybe it could for you as well

Answer (score 0):

activity_main.xml file needs to start with layout tag as shown below.

Comment: <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

</layout>

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29825019)