# Can't resolve Android databinding class

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

While using data binding , I am not able to get class `MainActivityBinding`  as per [Data Binding Guide](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html)

My layout name is `activity_main.xml`.
I am also see [Android - DataBinding - How and when the Binding classes will be generated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31365692/android-databinding-how-and-when-the-binding-classes-will-be-generated) but it can't help me.

Comment: What is your activity name??

Comment: @MD My actvity name is : `MainActivity.java`

Comment: Clean and Built project this will generate DataBinding class again as @RRR said

Comment: Already tried this things but it can't solve my problem!

Comment: Anyone facing the initial databinding setup try this http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2016/07/android-data-binding-part-1.html

Comment: I noticed that if the xml layout file starts directly from a constraint layout it won't work. Wrap everything in <layout>, move xmlns:android="...", xmlns:app="...", and xmlns:tools="..." to it, and then clean and rebuild. The binding object should appear. Also as the others said, make sure your naming is correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data Binding class not generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39483094/data-binding-class-not-generated)

Comment: http://mobologicplus.com/android-custom-data-binding-jetpack-component-directly-with-xml-view/ please check this tutorial

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thanks to all for your answer.I found solution with `ContentMainBinding` class name for data binding.
Lets me explain.

**NOTE:** While using layout with **`<include ...`** here is `<include layout="@layout/content_main"` having Data Binding functionality,  the class name related to include layout name. Here is the `ContentMainBinding`

My layout file are as below:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.databindingdemo.app.MainActivity">
    ...
    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
    ...
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And **content_main.xml** is layout where I added my Data Binding layout code.

So instead of using  **`MainActivityBinding`** it can resolved with **`ContentMainBinding`**

The code which work for me is below:

```
//Code for data binding
    ContentMainBinding contentMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.content_main);
    user = new User("Pranay", "Patel", "demoemail@gmail.com", "9999999999");
    contentMainBinding.setUser(user);
```

DONE.

Comment: You have fooled yourself, it will set your activity layout content_main.xml not activity_main.xml, What you have found is the default way to attach activity to layout.

Comment: **Don't follow this answer**, It will set layout `content_main`, If you want to inflate `activity_main.xml` then wrap it with `<layout` tag. and use `ActivityMainBinding class`.

Comment: Thanks @Khemraj for suggestion. It is an old answer. It may have an error. Can you please update answer if you can?

Answer (score 108):

DataBinding class will be generated based on your xml file name. It is clearly mentioned in doc you are following.

> By default, a Binding class will be generated based on the name of the layout file, converting it to Pascal case and suffixing “Binding” to it. The above layout file was main_activity.xml so the generate class was
>   MainActivityBinding

If your xml name is `activity_main.xml` than DataBinding class name will be `ActivityMainBinding`.

If your xml name is `main_activity.xml` than DataBinding class name will be `MainActivityBinding`.

**Dont forget to clean and build project once**

you can follow this tutorial for more about [DataBinding](http://androidgig.com/working-with-databinding-android/)

Comment: I am make sure with layout name as I already added in my question.

Comment: yes but in question you have mentioned `activity_main.xml` and using `MainActivityBinding` , it should be `ActivityMainBinding`

Comment: Make sure you rebuild the project after adding xml components, so that this class is generated.

Comment: If you struggle with unresolve symbol, try wrap you layout in `<layout>` tag.

Comment: Whenever you work with binding follow steps 1: first do dataBinding {enabled  = true } in gradle ..sync it ..2: use <layout > <data> </data></layout >tag if you have viewmodel then apply it in <variable > in your layout tag 3: then go to your activity and see ActivityMainBinding  there .. if not again rebuild it and see it must be there ..Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot. Was suffering from last hour and trying to type `MyActivityBinding` is of `ActivityMyBinding`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 27):

**TRY Renaming the xml file to another name and check if binding works** once it works rename it back to the one that was used.

That helped for **Android Studio 3.1**

Comment: It's better than restarting the IDE

Comment: Interestingly AS was not even renaming xml file. As I changed from explorer, binding class was auto detected. A classic bug! Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: awesome man..what a great answer. who could have thought renaming will fix it (hmmm...Android studio!!!..). i have been following it up by the books and was not working but this trick fixed it.

Comment: This work for me, but i have  lots of  layous, there is not other solution? (Android 3.2)

Comment: @GilbertoIbarra can you try restarting android studio

Comment: Bug still exists in Android Studio 3.2.1

Answer (score 18):

Make sure your activity_main.xml file is enclosed with **layout** tags like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Just having `<layout>` tag anywhere in the XML solves it.

Comment: It saves my day actually I forget to do that

Answer (score 9):

If **DataBinding class name is correct** and you used to clean and rebuild project but it still show error.
Then you try to **restart** AndroidStudio

Answer (score 8):

I've cleaned the project , Rebuild was done...but of no use.
Then invalidated caches and restarted the project that too didn't helped me.

Then I changed my xml file name - that worked fantastically fine.

So, I would like to share you one thing, please change your xml file name.

For eg: If your xml file is: activity_main.xml    and you can't get ActivityMainBinding in its Java class..........then change xml name to main_activity.xml      and then use MainActivityBinding in its java class as 'private MainActivityBinding binding;'

This will do most probably.

Answer (score 7):

In such cases, if neither rebuild nor invalidate caches work, then there must be an error in one of your xml files where you may have used @{xyz.abc} and there must be a problem with either xyz or abc in the xml.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem after changing the package name of my source, after I tried a lot of things (including mentioned here), I solved the problem by importing the databinding class manually:

```
import com.domain.my.databinding.MyActivityBinding;
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case DELETING the the app build folder  and then rebuilding the project solved my problem.

Even following steps did not work.

```
          1) Rebuild the project after adding the dataBinding  in gradle.

          2) Rebuild after adding layout tag in xml.

          3) cleaning the project

          4) rebuilding the project

          5) Restarted the Android Studio
```

After enabling the dataBinding in app gradle file please rebuild. Then we can find Binding class generated.

```
          If the layout name is fragment_home, The Binding class name will be FragmentHomeBinding.
```

Comment: I also tried to change bindings generation type from AS built-in to compiler and vice versa with restarting AS. Nothing happens. Yesterday everything worked fine

Comment: I waste one hour to solve this, then I tried your solution I change name of xml still it doesn't work then I rebuild, clean restart and it works. thanks

Answer (score 5):

Make sure to add below lines in build.gradle file

dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }

Answer (score 4):

Check that you activity/fragment's xml and class have consistent names; for example, if you have `TimePickerFragment` than xml file name should be `time_picker_fragment`.

It occurred to me that I had the layout named `fragment_time_picker`; after I changed it the binding was generated.

Answer (score 4):

> Binding class will be generated based on your layout file name. By
>   default, the name of the class is based on the name of the layout
>   file, converting it to Pascal case and adding the Binding suffix to it

for example, 
If your xml name is activity_main.xml then DataBinding class name will be ActivityMainBinding

then import the package:

```
import com.companyname.applicationname.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
```

then you can use it

```
ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
User user = new User("Test", "User");
binding.setUser(user);
```

Answer (score 4):

1. confirm add below code in `android {}` in `build.gradle (:app)`

```
    buildFeatures {
       viewBinding true
    }
```

2. `Binding`'s name is the corresponding **.xml file name** + "Binding", to check the .xml file, hold `command` and click the Activity name, then you jump to that .xml file OR you may get a dropdown list. No matter which, you can get the Binding.
   [image]

3. if still doesn't work then restart Android Studio

Answer (score 2):

Cant comment so i'll just add this in answer. I believe activity_main.xml will create ActivityMainBinding rather than MainActivityBinding as you mentioned. in some cases  where studio can't find the binding class then just invalidate the caches and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 2):

By default, a Binding class is generated based on the name of the layout file, starting it with upper-case, removing underscores ( _ ) and capitalizing the following letter and then suffixing “Binding”.

This class will be placed in a databinding package under the module package.

For example, the layout file `contact_item.xml` will generate `ContactItemBinding`.

If the module package is `com.example.my.app`, then it will be placed in `com.example.my.app.databinding`.

Binding classes may be renamed or placed in different packages by adjusting the class attribute of the data element. For example:

```
<data class="ContactItem">
    ...
</data>
```

This generates the binding class as `ContactItem` in the databinding package in the module package. If the class should be generated in a different package within the module package, it may be prefixed with `“.”`:

```
<data class=".ContactItem">
    ...
</data>
```

In this case, `ContactItem` is generated in the module package directly. Any package may be used if the full package is provided:

```
<data class="com.example.ContactItem">
    ...
</data>
```

Answer (score 2):

Restart Android studio or try to rename the XML file to another name and check if binding works once it works.

Answer (score 1):

In my case: **Solve problem without renaming XML file.**

I checked all case and I did everything like Invalidate Caches/Restart Android Studio, clean Project, Rebuild Project but But the error is not resolved.

Solution - Just I change some code and revert that code again in activity XML file or change code in XML file.

Note - This is very late answer but may be help others who don't want change XML file name. :)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue,

If your XML name is `activity_main.xml` than `DataBinding` class name will be `ActivityMainBinding`

If it is correct check if you add below code in your xml file,

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>
    <variable
        name="xyz"
        type="com.example.yourapp.classname" />
   />

</data>
```

if either method is not the issue, try

- clean project
- Rebuild project

Answer (score 1):

In my own experience, whenever you are including a layout, make sure the root view group has a layout id as shown below.
Note the `child_layout` id in the Child Layout file.

ParentLayout

```xml
        <include
            android:id="@+id/child_layout"
            layout="@layout/child_layout"/>
```

ChildLayout

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/child_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFe">
```

Answer (score 1):

This line inside `module/build.gradle` solved the issue for me:

```
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the following solutions which didn't work for me:
1) Invalidate cache and restart.
2) Restart Android Studio.
3) Rebuild project.

What DID fix the problem is:
1. Removing the "dataBinding" tag in the module gradle.build
2. Sync project
3  Return the "databinding" tag 
4. Sync project again.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting Android Studio, or manually searching for the ActivityMainBinding class and adding your import.

Put your data tag in your last included xml.
Here is an example:

```
MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Item item;
    ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        item = new Item();
        item.setChecked(true);
        item.setName("a");
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        binding.included.secondIncluded.setModel(item);


Item.java
public class Item extends BaseObservable {
    private String name;
    private Boolean checked;
    @Bindable
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    @Bindable
    public Boolean getChecked() {
        return this.checked;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name);
    }
    public void setChecked(Boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.checked);
    }
}


activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="abc"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        <include
            android:id="@+id/included"
            layout="@layout/included_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>


included_layout.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="123"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        <include
            android:id="@+id/second_included"
            layout="@layout/second_included_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>

second_included_layout.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="model"
            type="com.example.simone.twowaydatabinding.Item" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_included"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="xyz"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@={model.name}"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch_test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="@={model.checked}" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="change"
            android:onClick="button_onClick"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/world"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: why do you invoke setContentView() twice?

Comment: Not sure, I don't remember, this was a long time ago. I actually decided not to use Android data binding, I found it was inflexible.

Answer (score 0):

I recently installed android studio 3.5.3 and this issue rised so what i did is.

```
1) Clean Project
2) Update Gradle (as notification was coming) 
3) Rebuild project
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try to review your xml, if has a value which was setted wrong. This is probably something about wrong databinding settings

Answer (score 0):

Please put this code in build.gradle(app level), if not declared.

```
android {
    dataBinding.enabled true
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

// Android Studio 4.0

```
android {
    dataBinding.enabled true
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue. But after updating android to androidx solved like

try to change android.databinding.... to androidx.databinding...

Answer (score 0):

Enclosed with layout tags

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the accepted answer is outdated, the new answer is include this in the build.gradle(:app)

inside the android block

buildFeatures { viewBinding true }

works 100%

Answer (score 0):

**FYI,** I am using **Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1**

I tried all basic steps such as

- Clean & build project
- Invalidate caches and restart

All above not working.
Then I found it by myself after going through the Gradle file.

Add below code into `module/build.gradle` file inside `android` tag.

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```