# ViewDataBinding class does not contain my component after using <include/> tag

Tags: android, data-binding, android-xml

I was using direct childs in my layout xml, everthing was perfect while binding layouts with activity. I could use `binding.bannerPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);` but when i replaced direct childrens with `<include/>` tag, then i can not use `binding.bannerPager` any more, i searched this `bannerPager` in ViewDataBinding of my activity. But my bad i could not find that.

Here is my activity class.

```
public class ActivityRestaurantDetail extends BaseActivity {

    private ActivityRestaurantDetailBinding binding;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_restaurant_detail);
        binding.setActivity(this);
        binding.bannerPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

in activity_restaurant_detail.xml i have include  an layout which i need in many layouts.

```
                <include layout="@layout/layout_banner_image"/>
```

Here is layout_banner_image.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/banner_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/grey_rect"/>

    <com.amelio.utils.CircleView
        android:id="@+id/circle_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
        app:accent_color="@android:color/white"
        app:base_color="@color/light_grey"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My Question is :**

As solution i used findViewById then replaced `binding.bannerPager` with bannerPager.someMethod(), But i want to access components like before.

What should i do so i can access components like `binding.bannerPager`, and i dont have to use `findViewById`?

Comment: can I ask is there a reason why you don't wanna use findViewById() ?

Comment: Because i need to change that in 7 of activities where my layout is included.

Comment: you can replace them all just by using ctrl+shift+R and it will take hardly 1 minute to do so ;)

Comment: I just want to know why my component is not present in ViewDataBinding, if i included that. I have solutions too :)

Comment: This is not expected behavior. Perhaps i am missing something.

Comment: take a look at this answer it is related to your problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35883452/cant-resolve-android-databinding-class

Comment: @Umair You should see my comment there https://stackoverflow.com/a/35884291/6891563

Comment: Just clean and rebuild project did the trick for me. have you tried that?

Comment: Yes i have tried, i have found solution, that is posted in answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution finally,

First include `<layout/>` tag in included child layout xml and give an id to its parent view, (in my case RelativeLayout)

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlBannerPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/banner_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/grey_rect"/>

            <com.amelio.utils.CircleView
                android:id="@+id/circle_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
                app:accent_color="@android:color/white"
                app:base_color="@color/light_grey"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </layout>
```

Then your ViewDataBinding class will be generated for the child included layout. You can find that class from root ViewDataBinding by this way.

```
BannerImageBinding bannerImageBinding = DataBindingUtil.findBinding(findViewById(R.id.rlBannerPager));
```

Finally activity code looks like.

```
public class ActivityRestaurantDetail extends BaseActivity {

    private ActivityRestaurantDetailBinding binding;
    LayoutBannerImageBinding bannerImageBinding;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_restaurant_detail);
        binding.setActivity(this);
    bannerImageBinding = DataBindingUtil.findBinding(findViewById(R.id.rlBannerPager)); //added this line
         bannerImageBinding.bannerPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```