# Databiding Unresolve reference after update android studio 3.6

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have upgraded my android studio 3.6.

After updating the android studio data-binding class not generated.

Project Gradle and Version Info :

> buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
>    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'
>   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6
>   .4-all.zip

Below are the references for understand issue,

[implement data-binding in layout file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iM9bp.png)

[Not generate data-binding class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkCbj.png)

[it is data-binding package class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nOs2.png)

I had already performed below action,

1. Invalidate caches and restart
2. Remove the build folder and re-build project
3. Remove generated stub {true}

Now, I downgrade android studio to 3.5 my project is good working with databiding. But, not work in android studio 3.6

Answer (score 0):

AS 3.6 somehow renames submodule binding name. Use this workaround to name the binding manually : [stackoverflow.com/a/36377610/12966308](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36377610/12966308)

Comment: is a long process. I have a 100+ items layout. why I change manually the layout name. Not Work.

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue spent one day to resolved.

I found There is issue occur many android studio after update studio v3.6+ .

I resolved by installing Beta build of android studio.
you can download it from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview)

Comment: I thought about that but, I downgrade my android studio 3.5. Because it is not a stable version.