# Unresolved reference : ActivityMainBinding in Android Studio 3.6

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding, android-studio-3.6

I had updated an Android Studio 3.6 and then it shows me an error "Unresolved reference: ActivityMainBinding". But I have wondered that the project still working the same as the previous android studio version. Just only gave me an error "Unresolved reference: ActivityMainBinding".

Comment: If ur project not giving  any compiled time error then ur good.Actually Binding file are static file and when u update AS then these file are recreated but in code(may be import refer to old file) that why they so error in edtior.

Comment: Found solution?

Comment: @AminPinjari if you faced the same issue, then you need to update your Android Studio latest version.

Comment: @MaulikGajjar Studio version is latest one only, solved by doing regular tricks

Answer (score 4):

DataBinding class will be generated based on your XML file name.

If your xml name is activity_main.xml then the DataBinding class name will be ActivityMainBinding.

If your xml name is main_activity.xml then the DataBinding class name will be MainActivityBinding.

Don't forget to clean and build the project once

~

I also had this problem and the solution was shared from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35883531/7952086

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I didn't know it.

Answer (score 1):

What finally worked for me:

- clean
- invalidate/restart caches
- rebuild

Answer (score 0):

> Build -> Clean Project
>
> Build -> Rebuild Project

Hope this will help. Thanks

Comment: When you rebuild, don't you clean as well?

Answer (score 0):

Me also caused same problem, but resolves with adding "kapt" plugins.
Try to apply kapt plugins.

Comment: or changes kotlin-stdlib-jdk's dependencies  7 -> 8

Comment: On my project, I just upgraded the Android Studio 3.5 to 3.6 with all its dependencies.

I also changed the dependencies 7 to 8, but still the same problem. But I still wondering that when I compile the project and run it on the device, it couldn't give me an error, and it works fine.

I have created the same android code into the new project with some simple code and that couldn't give any issue with data binding in Android Studio 3.6.

I have done all the possibilities, but couldn't fix the issue.

Comment: Check https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149630915, hopefully the next patch may fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks for helping me here. But I have done the R&D when I am adding the custom layout files like as below

`android {
    defaultConfig {
        sourceSets {
            main.res.srcDirs = [
                    'src/main/res/splash'
            ]
        }
    }
}`

Then it will not generate the binding class file at all. But when I am cut that file and paste into the regular layout folder then it will be generated automatically and then again I move that file normal layout folder to custom layout folder then it will work normally.

Comment: for your helping, its resolved in the new patch of the android studio version.

Comment: I faced same today in 3.6.3

Answer (score 0):

you must make sure that :
1-your connexion internet is on"in manifest "(     )
2-in build gradle add in android{

```
    buildTypes {
    release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard- 
    rules.pro'
    }
}

dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}     
                             }
```

3-sync now
then ctrl+espace to the ActivityMainBinding

Comment: You already tried to restart the Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

*As of 5.5.2021:*

App **build.gradle**:

```
buildFeatures{
    viewBinding = true
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**:

```
..
import com.example.myapplication.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
}
..
```

**activity_main.xml:**

For simple view bindings (as opposed to data binding) you can leave the outer tag to default:`<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ..>`

No `<layout>` tag required!

---

Things to note:

1. My application is called MyApplication. Notice that line `com.example.myapplication.databinding.ActivityMainBinding` where the application name is converted to lowercase.
2. The above (1) mentioned line will also be automaticaly added when you type in `private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding`

This resolved my issues.

Answer (score -1):

Its nothing. You just need to do **"Invalidate cache and restart"** once.

It happens when some times the binding file is cleared when we clean the project. It will be created automatically.

Thank you.

Comment: Already did this. But still the same as, nothing any changes.

Comment: Post screenshot.