# Android Studio can not generate Binding class while use DataBinding

Tags: android-studio, android-databinding

- Android Studio : 3.1.0, 3.1.1
- Gradle         : 4.4
- Build Tools    : 3.1.0

I am using the DataBinding library. when I add a layout file to project or add any view into the layout file, Android Studio cannot generate a Binding class for the layout, until rebuilding the project.

layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.qk365.thweeks.MainViewModel" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_tab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#7343ea"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Design.Tab"
            app:tabTextColor="#181818" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/main_viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/main_tab">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

I checked Android Studio logs, when layout file changes, there always have error message.

```
2018-04-17 11:20:01,699 [e-1024-b02]  ERROR - .intellij.psi.impl.ElementBase - Element: class com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlFileImpl because: different providers: SingleRootFileViewProvider{myVirtualFile=file://E:/AndroidStudioProjects/thweeks/module-order/src/main/res/layout/order_fragment_pick_up_order.xml, content=VirtualFileContent{size=2845}}(5200996b); SingleRootFileViewProvider{myVirtualFile=file://E:/AndroidStudioProjects/thweeks/module-order/src/main/res/layout/order_fragment_pick_up_order.xml, content=VirtualFileContent{size=2845}}(398a3993)
invalidated at: see attachment 
com.intellij.psi.PsiInvalidElementAccessException: Element: class com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlFileImpl because: different providers: SingleRootFileViewProvider{myVirtualFile=file://E:/AndroidStudioProjects/thweeks/module-order/src/main/res/layout/order_fragment_pick_up_order.xml, content=VirtualFileContent{size=2845}}(5200996b); SingleRootFileViewProvider{myVirtualFile=file://E:/AndroidStudioProjects/thweeks/module-order/src/main/res/layout/order_fragment_pick_up_order.xml, content=VirtualFileContent{size=2845}}(398a3993)
invalidated at: see attachment
    at com.intellij.psi.util.PsiUtilCore.ensureValid(PsiUtilCore.java:502)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.smartPointers.SmartPointerManagerImpl.createSmartPsiElementPointer(SmartPointerManagerImpl.java:78)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.smartPointers.SmartPointerManagerImpl.createSmartPsiElementPointer(SmartPointerManagerImpl.java:69)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.smartPointers.SmartPointerManagerImpl.createSmartPsiElementPointer(SmartPointerManagerImpl.java:64)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.ElementBase$ElementIconRequest.<init>(ElementBase.java:183)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.ElementBase$ElementIconRequest.<init>(ElementBase.java:178)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.ElementBase.computeIcon(ElementBase.java:110)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.ElementBase.getIcon(ElementBase.java:86)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.lookup.DefaultLookupItemRenderer._getRawIcon(DefaultLookupItemRenderer.java:79)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.lookup.DefaultLookupItemRenderer.getRawIcon(DefaultLookupItemRenderer.java:48)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.JavaMethodCallElement.renderElement(JavaMethodCallElement.java:444)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.JavaCompletionUtil$4.renderElement(JavaCompletionUtil.java:468)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.JavaCompletionUtil$4.renderElement(JavaCompletionUtil.java:465)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.lookup.LookupElementDecorator$VisagisteDecorator.renderElement(LookupElementDecorator.java:179)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.lookup.LookupElementDecorator.renderElement(LookupElementDecorator.java:83)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.lookup.impl.LookupCellRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(LookupCellRenderer.java:150)
    at com.intellij.ui.ExpandedItemListCellRendererWrapper.getListCellRendererComponent(ExpandedItemListCellRendererWrapper.java:38)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paintCell(BasicListUI.java:209)
    at com.intellij.ui.components.WideSelectionListUI.paintCell(WideSelectionListUI.java:56)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paintImpl(BasicListUI.java:317)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.paint(BasicListUI.java:240)
    at com.intellij.ui.components.WideSelectionListUI.paint(WideSelectionListUI.java:32)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:780)
    at com.intellij.ui.components.JBList.paintComponent(JBList.java:186)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
    at com.intellij.ui.components.JBList.paint(JBList.java:118)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:728)
    at com.intellij.ui.components.JBViewport.paint(JBViewport.java:236)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1579)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1502)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:306)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
2018-04-17 11:20:01,699 [e-1024-b02]  ERROR - .intellij.psi.impl.ElementBase - Android Studio 3.1.1  Build #AI-173.4697961 
2018-04-17 11:20:01,699 [e-1024-b02]  ERROR - .intellij.psi.impl.ElementBase - JDK: 1.8.0_152-release 
2018-04-17 11:20:01,699 [e-1024-b02]  ERROR - .intellij.psi.impl.ElementBase - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
2018-04-17 11:20:01,699 [e-1024-b02]  ERROR - .intellij.psi.impl.ElementBase - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2018-04-17 11:20:01,699 [e-1024-b02]  ERROR - .intellij.psi.impl.ElementBase - OS: Windows 10 
2018-04-17 11:20:01,699 [e-1024-b02]  ERROR - .intellij.psi.impl.ElementBase - Last Action: EditorChooseLookupItem
```

Comment: It is a bug of Android Studio. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77607040

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data Binding class not generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39483094/data-binding-class-not-generated)

Comment: does it depend on gradle or sdk version?

Comment: This is a bug of Android Studio. Fixed in Android Studio 3.2.1.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. No matter what I tried it was not able to generate binding class. The trick was that you have to rename your layout xml file. Say you have a xml file **my_layout.xml** then rename it to **my_layout_temp.xml**. Now the binding class will be generated with name **MyLayoutTempBinding**. If you don't like the name then you can rename it back to **my_layout.xml**. At the end it will solve the binding class generate issue.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** For initial debugging steps see **Khemraj**'s answer here [Data Binding class not generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39483094/data-binding-class-not-generated)

- Android Studio : 3.1.4
- Gradle : 4.4
- Build Tools : 28.0.0

I can see the auto-generated binding classes momentarily after issuing a

**File > Invalidate Caches / Restart**

but only while the indexing is paused, immediately after Android Studio restarts (I should probably use something other than "databinding" for a test project name):

[image]

[image]

While paused, `ActivityMain2Binding` will be recognized by compiler, however the **build** and **make** operations are not available. Shortly after resuming the indexing the associated binding classes are removed and the IDE error mentioned in the OP is logged.

**Update** (2018.09.11)

Using a tip found in the bug post commented above (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77607040), I changed the **Data Binding setting** to

[image]

I then added a reference to the generated class

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error in the same environment as you.
But unfortunately, I could not resolve this problem with Android Studio 3.1.1.
For now, I'm using **Android Studio 3.2 Canary11 and it works fine**.

Comment: I have tried Canary 11 just now, but Binding class still cannot be generated.

Answer (score 0):

## The radical solution

You should add this in the `build.gradle(Module)` file to make the data binding enabled and press Sync

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a bug of Android Studio. Fixed in Android Studio 3.2.1.

Comment: No, it wasn't fixed.

Comment: This has trickled down to 3.5 too. I'll file a bug with them, if someone hasn't already.