# Android Databinding DatabindingUtil vs binding class

Tags: android, performance, android-databinding, android-jetpack, layout-inflater

I was wondering what is the difference between the following:

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.drawer_item_primary, parent, false);
```

vs

```
binding = DrawerItemPrimaryBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false);
```

Are there any performance differences? 
What is the preferred use case for each? 
Any other info would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `Binding class's inflate` as recommended in **[Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil.html#inflate(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean))**.

In **DataBindingUtil** class **[documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil#inflate(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean))** you can see.

> #### inflate
>
> ```
> T inflate (LayoutInflater inflater, 
>                 int layoutId, 
>                 ViewGroup parent, 
>                 boolean attachToParent)
> ```
>
> **Use this version only if layoutId is unknown in advance. Otherwise, use the generated Binding's inflate method to ensure type-safe
>   inflation.**

One option is to inflate by `DataBindingUtil` **but when only you don't have generated binding class**.

**You have generated `binding class`, use that class instead of using `DataBindingUtil`.**

**In Java**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    HomeFragmentBinding binding = HomeFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    //set binding variables here
    return binding.getRoot();
}
```

**In Kotlin**

```
lateinit var binding: HomeFragmentBinding 
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    binding = HomeFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}
```

If your layout biniding class is not generated @See **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579759/6891563)**.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, both the things are working same It will not affect on performances.
Only one minor difference which I have noticed is that if you are sure about which layout you want to inflate then you can use

`binding = DrawerItemPrimaryBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false);`

But If you want dynamic binding class then you can use

```
int layoutId = R.layout.drawer_item_primary;
DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, layoutId, parent, false);
```

**So `DrawerItemPrimaryBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false);` will always return our `DrawerItemPrimaryBinding` class.
where if we have to use  `DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, layoutId, parent, false);` then we can cast it as per requirement.**

Thank you.