# databinding.ActivityMainBinding unable to be imported in Android project

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have a working Android Studio project, also installed via USB on my smartphone, it's a simply basic calculator.
Now I have to rewrite the code for a lesson I teach, but Android Studio denies this import

```
import [com.username.projectname].databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
```

The app uses dataBinding I have enabled in Module:app and resync everything.

The old project works, the new one not, with the same code, cause of this import is refused.

Comment: see if it is defined in the xml and then make the project; sync might not be enough.

Comment: The original, working, calculator app has not defined anything about databinding. The one unusual code row I see is an id for the RelativeLayout used.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579759/6891563

Comment: See Update https://stackoverflow.com/a/72360048/12272687

Answer (score 2):

The `XML` needs a `<layout>` wrap alike this ...so that the desired class will be generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data class=".databinding.ActivityMainBinding">
        <!-- add variables & imports into here -->
    </data>

    <!-- and add the RelativeLayout into here -->

</layout>
```

Comment: It is new to me. The old app has not a data tag in the XML layout file. I have never needed to use it. I declare variables and imports in the .java file. XML file contains all graphics issues with IDs to link them with Java object.

Comment: I spent a couple hours looking for a solution to this, and for some reason this was the only one that worked. The `<data>` tag has to be specified or the class won't get generated for me.

Comment: It may even be required to add an empty `<data />` node, when it won't generate the bindings.

Answer (score 2):

Just add in the module based Grade file, the following

```
buildFeatures{
  viewBinding true
}
```

Comment: When faced with this issue I found that clearing this, resyncing the project, and then retyping it helped.

Answer (score 0):

add this code in the build Gradle (:app) file :

```
buildFeatures{ viewBinding true;}
```

Comment: He already enabled dataBinding in his app

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Sir you just need to add the following line in your layout in file activitymain.xml

```
class=".databinding.ActivityMainBinding"
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the problem is whenever you add

buildFeatures {viewBinding = true} in build.gradle.kts(module: app)
we forget to hit the (sync now) button
[Hit that button up there as it appears in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cyhy.png)

then go back to your Java code and add ActivityMainBinding binding(whatever you want). and it should work.