# Unresolved reference:ActivityMainBinding

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding

I know that this question have been asked before but I tried all the answers given and I still got nothing. I'm trying to define a `var binding:ActivityMainBinding` and I got an error

```
Unresolved reference:ActivityMainBinding
```

**Here is a part of my `mainActivity`**

```kotlin
import com.kolydas.aboutme.databinding.ActivityMainBinding //error

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding //error
    //....
}
```

**Here is my App `build.gradle`**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'    
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'    
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'   

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kolydas.aboutme"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding{
        enabled = true  //enable data binding
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.4.0"
}
```

And of course in my xml file i have the layout /layout tags in the beginning and in the end.

Comment: please try like this   "val binding: ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)"

Comment: @android doesn't work.Something is wrong with the libraries i believe because also in my imports i got the error(on the line i import the ActivityMainBinding)

Comment: have you imported the "import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil"?

Comment: please update your library with "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.5.0-alpha13"

Comment: What gradle version are you using?

Comment: Did you try rebuilding your project?

Comment: a.  Does your xml file have the layout tag enclosing everything else? Without it, no binding class will be created. Also: try to comment out that line and build the app, maybe the binding class hasn't been built yet

Comment: @RahulAgrawal wow that was it :O

Comment: I have faced similar issue before and had read somewhere that the databinding file is created only on successful compile of the application.
Glad i was of some help. @AlexKolydas

Comment: I had similar challenge, after some time it worked.
I think you should also put on your internet connection

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sometimes all you need is clean and rebuild the project.

```
Build -> Clean Project 
Build -> Rebuild Project
```

This would be enough for generating the binding classes.

[Generated binding classes](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/generated-binding)

Comment: Yep. That has worked for me! No actual configuration changes necessary. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Doing this all the time is boring. Isn't there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 48):

None of the suggestions worked for me, because the correct way to resolve this issue is to put (app level build.gradle)

```
buildFeatures{
   dataBinding = true
   viewBinding = true
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks :)

Comment: This looks like the "official" way to do it as it is described in [Android Codelabs](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-tip-calculator#2).

Comment: for Kotlin add in plugins  { id  'kotlin-kapt' }

Comment: Worked like a charm for me as well, didn't put databinding, my deepest thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Try to add in build.gradle (Module:app)

```
buildFeatures {
   viewBinding true
}
```

Comment: Yes, this finally lets me add the correct import statement.  :)

Answer (score 7):

I see this relatively old bug every now and then (regardless of using kotlin or not, but it's very common when you convert a class from java to kotlin) and it's still an issue with the newest android studio. Cleaning the project does not help in many cases. Whenever there seems to be no valid reason for this issue, following trick *always* solves the issue for:

**Solution 1**

Rename the xml file (e.g. `main_activity2.xml), clean the project and try to do change` MainActivityBinding`to`MainActivity2Binding`

**Solution 2** (*I just found this trick recently but it seems to work reliably as well*)

Alternatively  make a change inside the problematic xml file (add a view or so or change an attribute), clean the project and it's working again.

*Background*

I see this happening when moving layouts between modules e.g. and sometimes in other cases as well. But refactoring the structure regularly results in this issue. There is some caching problem that leads to this problem sometimes and in many cases, even deleting all temp files and cleaning the project does not help but only changing the xml or renaming it does solve the issue...

Comment: Refactoring caused the issue on Bitrise. Had to clear the bitrise build cache for it to work

Answer (score 4):

It's not about the Gradle file. It is about the XML file.

First, make sure that your layout tag contains just this line:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

or these lines:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Then rebuild the project.

Comment: I had layout_height and width on my Layout root node, but when only namespace attributes where left, the system proposed me to convert it to databinding layout. I cleaned and rebuild project, and the problem got solved.

Comment: In my case I had the wrong context on the xml file. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just to sum up all useful actions:

1. Check if you got top-level `<layout>` tag in respective .xml file.
2. Verify build.gradle (app) if binding `enabled=true` in android section.
3. Verify imports in activity file:

   ```
   import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil
   import com.example.[YOUR_APP_NAME].databinding.ActivityMainBinding
   ```
4. Try to rebuild project **Build > Rebuild** Project after every action just to refresh and check the results.

   Good Luck! It's just beginning of this Android journey:)

Comment: You can also try to reboot your IDE if it's not refreshing code, but it extremely rare.

Answer (score 3):

Faced similar issue while following the Android Udacity Lessons Creating and Adding Fragment.

In my case the TitleFragment class was unable to resolve `com.example.android.navigation.databinding.FragmentTitleBinding`.

I had to add empty `<data></data>` tag in fragment_title.xml file and clean/rebuild the project for the compilation error to go away.

Comment: in case someone  needs to see the code here is the github link  https://github.com/udacity/andfun-kotlin-android-trivia/blob/Step.01-Exercise-Creating-and-Adding-a-Fragment/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigation/MainActivity.kt

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did.
Step 1.
Go to build.gradle(Module:app),
add this in android , below buildTypes:

```
buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
```

Step 2. In activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
<!--you can add some xml tag here-->
</layout>
```

Step 3. In MainActivity.kt (testapp is my project)

```
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import com.example.testapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
```

Step 4.

```
Go to Build->Clean Project 
and then Rebuild Project
```

Answer (score 3):

set in `build.gradle`(app) :

```
android
{
buildFeatures
 {
 dataBinding = true
 viewBinding = true
 }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 3):

Update, **due to version '7.2.0'**

after add

```
buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        dataBinding = true
    }
```

then in Xml

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
```

Finally , must add the **name of the layout (XML)** file

```
import com.src.example.databinding.NameOfXML
```

for example:

```
R.layout.new_face -----> NewFaceBinding
```

then in Activity

```
 val binding  = NewFaceBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
```

Moreover the id calling also is changed

in xml

```
android:id="@+id/progress_bar2"
```

in Activity

```
binding.progressBar2.
```

Answer (score 3):

copy this code in your `build.gridle(:app)` in `buildTypes` section and then click sync now below the file window tab.Then do `Build -> Rebuild Project`

Note: There is no `=` sign after `dataBinding`

```
buildFeatures{
   dataBinding  true
   viewBinding = true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.4.0"
```

change to

```
kapt 'androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:3.4.0'
```

Comment: This worked for view binding. Had to include `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` in the gradle file.

Answer (score 2):

Just add
`import com.example.tiptime.databinding.ActivityMainBinding`
in your MainActivity.kt file

Answer (score 2):

I just want to contribute my answer here, so a person who's scrolling can try the different options. This finally worked for me:

After adding databinding enabled in app gradle file, you add the  tags in the layout xml right? **Ensure that it is "<layout>" not "<Layout>" (lowercase not uppercase)**.

Also whichever is the base viewgroup in your layout, you can simply click the bulb that you get when you hover over its name, and click on "convert to data binding", it'll add the right tags for you. THEN you can try to get the ActivityMainBinding class in your activity (if it doesn't work try rebuilding once)

Answer (score 2):

**Summary:**

Assuming that you already setup your setup the data binding and/or view binding in `build.gradle` (app) as explained others answers in this post...

When you change the name of your activity, the name of the binding must changes too.

For example: If you change the name of your activity from `MapsActivity` to `SomeMapsActivity` then your import changes from:

```kotlin
import com.myexample.exampleapp.databinding.ActivityMapsBinding
```

to:

```kotlin
import com.myexample.exampleapp.databinding.ActivitySomeMapsBinding
```

This means that you must go thorough the code and change it there too:

From:

```kotlin
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMapsBinding
```

To:

```kotlin
private lateinit var binding: ActivitySomeMapsBinding
```

From:

```kotlin
binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

To:

```kotlin
binding = ActivitySomeMapsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

**Description:**

I encounter this issue when I tried to have two different Maps activities by duplicating an existent one.

First, you need to make sure that each Map activity has its own layout.

In my case, more than a layout, its a `FragmentContainerView`:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.FirstMapActivity" />
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.SecondMapActivity" />
```

Please notices `tool:context` since that value must indicate what activity is this fragment binding with. In my case, both `FirstMapActivity` and `SecondMapActivity` are both inside the `ui` package.

Next, look into the imports of each Map activity.

`ActivityMapsBinding` is in red, isn't it?. That's because it isn't the right binding.

```kotlin
import com.myexample.exampleapp.databinding.ActivityMapsBinding
```

Since you changed the name of the map activity, the name of the binding binding changed name too.

In my case, on the first map, it changes from:

```kotlin
import com.myexample.exampleapp.databinding.ActivityMapsBinding
```

to:

```kotlin
import com.myexample.exampleapp.databinding.ActivityFirstMapsBinding
```

On the second map, it changes from

```kotlin
import com.myexample.exampleapp.databinding.ActivityMapsBinding
```

to:

```kotlin
import com.myexample.exampleapp.databinding.ActivitySecondMapsBinding
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can not access to **ActivityMainBinding** in **MainActivity.kt**

1. Problem ⛔

   If you you call **ActivityMainBinding** Type in **MainActivity.kt** without adding  in your **activity_main.xml**, **ActivityMainBinding** will be not read it in **MainActivity.kt**
2. Solution ✅

   2.1. enabled dataBinding in build.gradle (App)

   2.2. add  in your activity_main.xml

   2.3. call ActivityMainBinding in your MainActivity.kt
3. Warning ⚠️

   You don't need call viewBinding in in build.gradle (App)
4. Overview example ️
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

In my project, if you don’t wrap activity_main.xml in root element layout, data binding doesn’t work...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/resycler_data"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: Please avoid images of code! You can format code in your answer with the {} button

Comment: For some questions about unresolved FragmentTitleBinding, please try to replace the default <FrameLayout> tag with <layout> tag in your res/layout/fragment_title.xml

Answer (score 1):

Your xml must started as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Answer (score 0):

A binding class is generated for each layout file. The default naming convention used for the generated class is based on the name of the layout file. It converts the layout name to **Pascal case notation** and will be adding a **Binding suffix** to that. If the layout filename is `activity_main.xml` so the corresponding generated class is named as **ActivityMainBinding**. This class holds all the bindings info.
Source: [Databinding in Android](https://proandroiddev.com/databinding-in-android-b3cb41a8e0c5)

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this error with the fourth line.

`activity_main.xml`

```
package com.example.<your-project-name>

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.<your-project-name>.databinding.ActivityMainBinding // <---- Add this line

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
```

Make sure the file name creates the object automatically.

- `activity_main.xml` -> `ActivityMainBinding`
- `result_profile.xml` -> `ResultProfileBinding`

ref. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Answer (score 0):

one of the reasons you will see this error if you are using `tools:viewBindingIgnore="true"` in the `layout.xml` file mistakenly.