# Cannot find the getter for attribute ImageView while using Databinding in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-imageview, android-databinding

I am trying to learn **data binding** with **Kotlin** and I was able to implement it successfully for edit text and text views. After that I am trying to use it for Image Views. I am currently trying to give an option to users to choose their profile picture by clicking on the imageview. This code works properly but when I try to set the image to the view using data binding adapter , I get the following error.

> Found data binding errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the getter for attribute 'android:userImage' with value type java.lang.String on de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView. file:/home/parangat-pt-p10/AndroidStudioProjects/ReUsableAndroid/reusable_android/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_signup.xml loc:25:12 - 31:48 ****\ data binding error ****

Below is my code for the same.

**Layout code of ImageView**

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:userImage="@{signup.userImage}"
            android:id="@+id/iv_user"
            android:src="@drawable/profile"/>
```

**Model class code**

```
    class Signup {
    var userImage=""
    var firstName=""
    var lastName=""
    var phoneNumber=""
    var postCode=""
    var country=""
    var email=""
    var password=""
    var confirmPassword=""
    var isAcceptTerms=false

    @BindingAdapter("android:userImage")
    fun loadImage(view: CircleImageView, imageUrl: String) {
        userImage=imageUrl
        Glide.with(view.context).load(imageUrl).into(view)

    }
}
```

And this is what I am doing after user selected image

```
override fun onSingleImageSelected(uri: Uri?) {
    signupBinding.signup?.loadImage(iv_user,uri.toString())

}
```

Since this is written in kotlin, therefore there is no need to define the getter and setter methods but the error states that no getter method found.

As suggested by Enzokie, I created the binding Adapter in separate file like below

```
@BindingAdapter("userImage")
fun loadImage(view: CircleImageView, imageUrl: String) {
    Glide.with(view.context).load(imageUrl).into(view)
}
```

But I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Correct Approach

- Use either [Observable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BaseObservable) / [Live Data](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata).
- Make a binding adapter class individually and don't mess-up things in model.

  - Yes tutorials do that, because they are just teaching you.
  - Just make one common binding adapter (like `android:src`) for whole app.
- No need to use custom namespace, until when you need it. So you can use `android:src` instead of `android:userImage`.
- No need to use `CircleImageView` in `BindingAdapter`, make common adapter with `ImageView` because `CircleImageView` is child of `ImageView`.

### Final code

- If you need to manually change fields like `signup.userImage = "someUrl"` then use `Bindable` and `notify`, other wise no need of both.
- If you use `ObservableField` instead of extending `BaseObservable` class, then you don't need to use `Bindable` and `notify`.

**Signup.class**

```
class Signup : BaseObservable() {
    @get:Bindable
    var userImage: String = ""
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.userImage)
        }
}
```

**DataBindingAdapter.kt**

```
 // binding adapter for setting url/uri on ImageView
@BindingAdapter("android:src")
fun setImageUrl(view: ImageView, url: String) {
    Glide.with(view.context).load(url).into(view)
}
```

**layout.xml**

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            ...
            android:src="@{signup.userImage}"/>
```

Now you can set `binding.signup.userImage = "Url"`, it will refract on UI automatically.

## That's all!

#### Reason of Fail

When you use data binding, and you want UI automatic update after setting fields. then your model should be one of below :

- Either extend [BaseObservable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BaseObservable)
- Or fields must be [Observable fields](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability)
- Or using [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)

In your case, initially your URL is empty (""). Now when you set image after some time programmatically, then UI is not notified because you are not using any observing option like I said above.

#### Bit more info

The difference between both is, Live data is Android Lifecycle Aware (Activity/ Fragments/ Services).

> LiveData is an observable data holder class. Unlike a regular
> observable, LiveData is lifecycle-aware, meaning it respects the
> lifecycle of other app components, such as activities, fragments, or
> services. This awareness ensures LiveData only updates app component
> observers that are in an active lifecycle state.

Comment: I will try this now but issue in my case was that I was not even able to build my project.

Comment: See this answer, I tried to cover up all issues I faced in binding here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579759/6891563

Comment: How to call the BindingAdapter loadImage method. I can't see in your code where it is called

Comment: Bro, it is data binding, you need not to call it.

Comment: I added layout code here. You need not set src and userimage both, as I have created binding adapter by name (android:src) so just use it.

Comment: When url is changed, then binding internally calls binding adapter method. You can see binding internal classes, when project build successful then press alt + F7 on setImageUrl method.

Comment: If I use @bindable attribute in the model class, it keeps giving error in the BR file. While if I remove it then it build successfully

Comment: BR file mean Binding Resources, It is generated when you have successfully build project. If you are not getting suggestion then import by `import com.yourpackage.BR`

Comment: I recently read that Bindable should be used when you only want a single field to be observed for data change. But in my case, I have already  extended Base observable so I think specifying @Bindable again is not going to work

Answer (score 1):

try by removing android TAG

```
@BindingAdapter("userImage")
fun loadImage(view: CircleImageView, imageUrl: String) {
    userImage=imageUrl
    Glide.with(view.context).load(imageUrl).into(view)

}
```

AND

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:userImage="@{signup.userImage}"
        android:id="@+id/iv_user"
        android:src="@drawable/profile"/>
```

Comment: I can't add the curly braces inside the Binding adapter annotation . Android Studio gives error as soon as type that

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
@BindingAdapter({"bind:userImage"})
```

Instead of this

```
@BindingAdapter("android:userImage")
```

And in `CircleImageView`

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:userImage="@{signup.userImage}"
            android:id="@+id/iv_user"
            android:src="@drawable/profile"/>
```

here is the good article for [**`Loading images with data binding`**](https://android.jlelse.eu/loading-images-with-data-binding-and-picasso-555dad683fdc)

Comment: @VivekMishra check this article https://android.jlelse.eu/loading-images-with-data-binding-and-picasso-555dad683fdc

Comment: I have some issue with the link's code. Android studio doesn't let me add curly braces inside the binding adapter (). I tried like this     `@BindingAdapter({"bind:userImage"})`

Comment: @VivekMishra check this hope this gives u some tips [Custom attributes using BindingAdapters in Kotlin](https://proandroiddev.com/custom-attributes-using-bindingadapters-in-kotlin-971ef8fcc259)

Answer (score 0):

Alongwith the answer given by Khemraj make sure you have marked Binding Adapter as `@JvmStatic` and it should be added above `@BindingAdapter` annotation. I wasted a whole day as I had added jvmstatic after Binding Adapter annotation.

```
object ImageBindingAdapter {
@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("android:src")
fun setImage(imageView: ImageView, uri: String) {
    Glide.with(imageView.context).load(uri).placeholder(R.drawable.no_image).error(R.drawable.no_image).centerCrop().into(imageView)
}}
```