# Data Binding Package does not exist?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter

I have Custom View in Nested Package
   default package : **com.example.testing**
   I created a custom class view in the subpackage like
   **com.example.testing.login.pinview** and inserted in layout like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.example.testing.login.pinview
            android:id="@+id/testingview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

After rebuilding the android project i am getting error

**error: package login does not exist**

Even i already enabled databinding in gradle

Please anyone help i stuck from 2 days

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your posted XML. Can you post more detail about error? Is there some other information before this error message?

Comment: Did you check all possible causes of data binding fail here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579759/6891563

Comment: error: package Login.View does not exist
      Login.View.TestingView loginview)

Comment: It's login not "Login" Caps matters in package names

Comment: did you create `login` package  with in your `com.example.testing` ?

Comment: yes i created login package inside com.example.testing