# How to fix cannot find symbol view-model-name-BindingImpl when using two-way databinding in Android

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

I am implementing Two-Way DataBinding with Android Architecture Components using `LiveData` and `ViewModel`, but when I build the project it gives

```
error: cannot find symbol
import package.[layout_name]BindingImpl;
```

in `DataBinderMapperImpl.java`

I followed official documentation and looked at SO for answers but none of them had workable solutions.

already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54537450/android-recyclerview-adapter-databinding-cannot-find-symbol-layoutbindingimp) one and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39483094/data-binding-class-not-generated/51579759#51579759) one

**layout.xml**

```xml
    <data>
        <import type="package.ViewModel" /> // this line was added from an answer but didn't work
        <variable
            name="model"
            type="package.ViewModel"/>
    </data>

// an input field I want to bind data with
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@={model.email}" // if I remove this line, builds fine
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
```

Extending my `ViewModel` from `AndroidViewModel` instead of `BaseObservable` as mentioned in documentation

**ViewModel.kt**

```
    private val email: MutableLiveData<String> by lazy { MutableLiveData<String>() }
    @Bindable // tried to change the return type to String, still no luck
    fun getEmail(): LiveData<String> {
        return email
    }

    fun setEmail(email: String) {
        this.email.value = email
    }
```

This is how I bind `ViewModel` with `View`

**Activity.kt**

```
binding.model = ViewModelProviders.of(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory
            .getInstance(application))
            .get(LoginViewModel::class.java)
```

What am I missing? Already included all things pre-databinding and if I had replaced `ViewModel` in `layout` with a `data class` and tried to get data from it, that works fine but with `@{}` in `layout`

**EDIT**

Okay, so when I expose `email` as `public`, it compiles and binding works, but I can't make its setter and getter `public`, I mean when I try to expose it from its getter and setter, IDE says that these are already `private` `fun`ctions and cannot be `override`n?

How can I make this property expose through `fun`ctions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on Reddit.

For two-way databinding to work, you have to expose your fields and they should be `MutableLiveData` like

```
val email = MutableLiveData<String>()
```

since `kotlin` already has `get` and `set` properties, they'll be used by `Binding` classes for fields

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and none of the solutions presented here worked.
In my case, the problem was because I had a Double property.

I changed it to String and it worked.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I had a MutableLiveData<Int> and it was not working. I changed it to MutableLiveData<String> and it compiled! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **getter** of particular variable directly using **`get()`** method to variable *(also works for setter too as **`set(value)`**)* like below :

```
@get:Bindable // We make getter method bindable for data-binding
val email = MutableLiveData<String>()
    get() { // Try to provide getter method like this
        return field as LiveData<String>
    }
    set(data) { // Try to provide setter method like this
        if(field.value != data.value) // To avoid infinite loop
            field.value = data.value
    }
```

Comment: thanks but for two-way binding to work you have to expose the field as `MutableLiveData` and make it default