# how to use dataBindingUtil to inflate every layout (using android studio)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

i was told to set dataBindingUtil in build.gradle
after doing that i am being told to use dataBindingUtil to inflate every layout
not sure how to use dataBindingUtil to inflate every layout

Comment: you can find the **data binding** in [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding).
You may find also very interesting its related but diferrent **view binding** in [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) that looks closer to what you seem to look for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dataBinding alongside viewBinding to declare your view hassle-free in your Kotlin/Java file. In your app build.gradle file add the following

```
android {
    ......
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
        viewBinding true
    }
}
```

Now convert the xml layout you want to use data binding in to data binding layout by wrapping it in

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewmodel"
        type="com.myapp.data.ViewModel" />
</data>
<ConstraintLayout... /> <!-- UI layout's root element -->
```

In order to inflate and use this variable in your Kotlin file, add the following line

```
ViewNameBinding binding = ViewNameBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

Here ViewNameBinding is auto generate as per you view name.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Binding class's inflate` as recommended in [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil.html#inflate(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)).

DataBindingUtil used **when only you don't have generated binding class**.

You can generated binding class, use that class instead of using DataBindingUtil.

**In Kotlin**

```
lateinit var binding: HomeFragmentBinding 
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    binding = HomeFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}
```

If your layout biniding class is not generated @See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579759/6891563).