# BindingAdapter class not generated

Tags: android-databinding

I have implemented @BindingAdapters in many projects. Recently created a new project in Android Studio Dolphin. added plugin kotlin-kapt and other required dependencies. Not able to figure out what is going wrong. when i use the binding adapter inside xml as attribute. there is an compilation error.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was package line. when we generate a kotlin class file or move a file from different project the package line if not present the generated classes won't be able to import them as they don't have the path from which they can be imported. i added the package line which is the 1st line in every class or file and issue was solved. silly one but took 2 days