cannot find symbol class ActivityMainBindingImpl
I am currently learning about Data binding and I did exactly as the tutorial but I keep getting the error "error: cannot find symbol class ActivityMainBindingImpl" when I run the app no matter how many times I run the app. It generates a DataBinderMapperImpl java file where this shows "Cannot resolve symbol 'ActivityMainBindingImpl"
Main:
package com.example.quadraticequationsolver;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;

import com.example.quadraticequationsolver.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityMainBinding ob1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ob1 = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });
        Solve s = new Solve(ob1);
        ob1.setVar(s);
    }
}

XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="var"
            type="com.example.quadraticequationsolver.Solve" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/wall"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/e1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="323dp"
            android:hint="Enter a"
            android:text="@={var.a}"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/e2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:hint="Enter b"
            android:text="@={var.b}"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/e1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/e3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
            android:hint="Enter c"
            android:text="@={var.c}"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/e2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="133dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:onClick="@={var::solveequation}"
            android:text="find roots"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/e3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/e3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="143dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="140dp"
            android:text="Solution"
            android:textColor="#07ADF8"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/e1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>

Model class:
package com.example.quadraticequationsolver;

import android.view.View;

import androidx.databinding.BaseObservable;
import androidx.databinding.Bindable;

import com.example.quadraticequationsolver.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class Solve extends BaseObservable {
    String a, b, c;
    ActivityMainBinding ob;

    public Solve(ActivityMainBinding ob) {
        this.ob = ob;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(String c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void solveequation(View v) {
        int a1 = Integer.parseInt(getA());
        int b1 = Integer.parseInt(getB());
        int c1 = Integer.parseInt(getC());
        double d = b1 * b1 - 4 * a1 * c1;
        double x1;
        double x2;
        if (d > 0) {
            x1 = (-b1 + Math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a1);
            x2 = (-b1 - Math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a1);
            ob.textView.setText("X1:" + x1 + "    X2:" + x2);
        } else if (d == 0) {
            x1 = (double) (-b1) / (2 * a1);
            ob.textView.setText("X1:" + x1);
        } else {
            ob.textView.setText("Imaginary Roots");
        }
    }
}

Gradle::app
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.quadraticequationsolver"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.quadraticequationsolver"
        minSdk = 25
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    buildFeatures{
        dataBinding {
            enable=true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    constraints {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0"){
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0"){
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
    }
    implementation(libs.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.activity)
    implementation(libs.constraintlayout)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.ext.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)
}

I've enabled databinding feature in the gradle file, tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, updating my sdk, invalidating cache and restarting, checked my xml file and model class.
Please help. Thankyou!

Did you check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579759/6891563

If you're expecting to have "Binding classes automatically generated for you, I think you need to add viewBinding into your project as well.  This can be done directly in your build.gradle file:
//
...
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding = true
    viewBinding = true
}

You can read more about viewBinding in their official docs: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#kts

dataBinding is viewBinding and more, enabling both is pointless (as dataBinding generates the binding classes as well)

And yet your current solution cannot find the generated class.  Have you tried enabling viewBinding as well?

probably invalidating the caches would do the job, as it always does (or making sure all views we want access to have an android:id set

i tried enabling viewBinding and invalidating cache. Still shows the error.
